# How can I put multiple Java exercises into one class in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to put 3 separate Java exercises (classes) into one class. Could someone please show me how to do it? Thanks! Here are the programs:

--

```
public class Chapter3Exercise1
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        printNumbers(15);
        System.out.println();
        printNumbers(5);

    }

    public static void printNumbers(int x)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(("[") + (i) + ("]") + (" "));
        }

    }
}

public class Chapter3Exercise4
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print(largerAbsVal(11, 2));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(largerAbsVal(4, -5));

    }

    public static int largerAbsVal(int x, int y)
    {
        return Math.max(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y));

    }

}

public class Chapter3Exercise5
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print(largestAbsVal(7, -2, -11));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(largestAbsVal(-4, 5, 2));
    }

    public static int largestAbsVal(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int abs1 = Math.max(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y));
        int abs2 = Math.max(Math.abs(y), Math.abs(z));
        return Math.max(abs1, abs2);

    }

}
```

--

Comment: If you want in same file why each class has it's own main method?

Comment: I don't understand.  Why do you need to do this?  What do you really want to do?  This is not a clear question.

Comment: Please **do not** edit your question to only contain garbage. Instead, please take the time to edit your post to contain a good, well thought-out question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Chapter3
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    excercise1();
    excercise2();
    ..........
}
public void excercise1()
{
    printNumbers(15);
    System.out.println();
    printNumbers(5);

}

public static void printNumbers(int x)
{

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(("[") + (i) + ("]") + (" "));
    }

}

public void excercise2()
{
    System.out.print(largerAbsVal(11, 2));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print(largerAbsVal(4, -5));
}

public static int largerAbsVal(int x, int y)
{
    return Math.max(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y));

}
 .................
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class mainclass
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
        printNumbers(15);
        System.out.println();
        printNumbers(5);
    System.out.print(largerAbsVal(11, 2));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(largerAbsVal(4, -5));
    System.out.print(largestAbsVal(7, -2, -11));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(largestAbsVal(-4, 5, 2));


    }
    public static void printNumbers(int x) {

           for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
                System.out.print(("[")+(i) + ("]")+ (" "));    
       }
    public static int largerAbsVal(int x, int y) {
        return Math.max(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y));

       }
    public static int largestAbsVal(int x, int y, int z) {
        int abs1 = Math.max(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y));
        int abs2 = Math.max(Math.abs(y), Math.abs(z));
        return Math.max(abs1, abs2);


       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to figure it out if I tell you: 
1) You can only have one main method in the class.
2) You can put all of the instance methods in one class.

The rest is copy and paste!

Answer (score 0):

A `public` java class must be present in its own `.java` file. If you want to put all of them in a single file, you should remove the `public` access specifier. But that would make those classes package-private, i.e. they will not be accessible from other packages.

```
class Chapter3Exercise1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        printNumbers(15);
        System.out.println();
        printNumbers(5);
    }

    public static void printNumbers(int x)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(("[") + (i) + ("]") + (" "));
        }
    }
}

class Chapter3Exercise4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print(largerAbsVal(11, 2));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(largerAbsVal(4, -5));
    }

    public static int largerAbsVal(int x, int y)
    {
        return Math.max(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y));
    }
}

class Chapter3Exercise5
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print(largestAbsVal(7, -2, -11));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(largestAbsVal(-4, 5, 2));
    }

    public static int largestAbsVal(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        int abs1 = Math.max(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y));
        int abs2 = Math.max(Math.abs(y), Math.abs(z));
        return Math.max(abs1, abs2);
    }
}
```

BTW, once you move all the classes into a single file in eclipse and try to run, it would ask to choose the class whose `main` method should be run, since each of your class has a `main` method defined.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is you have **only one public class** and **one main method** in a single java file.